# Poly fold return type not inferred correctly

Tags: scala, shapeless

I am trying to create a poly function that folds over a tuple of `Foo`s:

```
case class Foo[A](a: A)

object extractFold extends Poly2 {
  implicit def default[A, As <: HList]: Case.Aux[Foo[A], Foo[As], Foo[A :: As]] = {
    ???
  }
}

def extract[In, A <: HList, B <: HList](keys: In)
  (implicit
    gen: Generic.Aux[In, A],
    folder: RightFolder.Aux[A, Foo[HNil], extractFold.type, Foo[B]],
    tupler: Tupler[B])
: Foo[tupler.Out] = {
  ???
}

val result = extract((Foo(1), Foo("a")))
```

The function works at runtime, but the compiler inferred result type is always `Foo[Unit]` which is not right - in this example it should be `Foo[(Int, String)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think that

> the compiler inferred result type is always Foo[Unit]

?

The following code

```
import shapeless.ops.hlist.{RightFolder, Tupler}
import shapeless.{::, Generic, HList, HNil, Poly2}
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{typeOf, Type, TypeTag}

object App {
  def getType[T: TypeTag](t: T): Type = typeOf[T]

  case class Foo[A](a: A)

  object extractFold extends Poly2 {
    implicit def default[A, As <: HList]: Case.Aux[Foo[A], Foo[As], Foo[A :: As]] = 
      at { case (Foo(a), Foo(as)) => Foo(a :: as) }
  }

  def extract[In, A <: HList, B <: HList](keys: In)(implicit
    gen: Generic.Aux[In, A],
    folder: RightFolder.Aux[A, Foo[HNil], extractFold.type, Foo[B]],
    tupler: Tupler[B]
  ): Foo[tupler.Out] =
    Foo(tupler(folder(gen.to(keys), Foo(HNil)).a))

  val result = extract((Foo(1), Foo("a")))

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(
      getType(result)
    )
  }
}
```

prints

```
App.Foo[(Int, java.lang.String)]
```

Moreover, if you change the line

```
val result: Foo[Unit] = extract((Foo(1), Foo("a")))
```

the code doesn't compile.

---

By the way, the same can be done with

```
import shapeless.PolyDefns.~>
import shapeless.ops.hlist.{Comapped, NatTRel, Tupler}
import shapeless.{Generic, HList, Id}

object App {
  case class Foo[A](a: A)

  def extract[In, A <: HList, B <: HList](keys: In)(implicit
    gen: Generic.Aux[In, A],
    comapped: Comapped.Aux[A, Foo, B],
    natTRel: NatTRel[A, Foo, B, Id],
    tupler: Tupler[B]
  ): Foo[tupler.Out] =
    Foo(tupler(natTRel.map(new (Foo ~> Id) { def apply[T](foo: Foo[T]) = foo.a }, gen.to(keys))))

  val result = extract((Foo(1), Foo("a")))

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(result)//Foo((1,a))
  }
}
```

Comment: if I add the type annotation `result: Foo[(Int, String)]` (to the first example) then I get the same compilation error as `result: Foo[Unit]` - do you?

Comment: however you were right with `Comapped` - that was the missing witness to tie `A` to `B`, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone with a better understanding of shapeless can provide you a better answer. According to my understanding the problem lies at the type inference step. If you specify all the types explicitly as in

```
val result: Foo[(Int, String)] = extract[(Foo[Int], Foo[String]),
    Foo[Int] :: Foo[String] :: HNil,
    Int :: String :: HNil]((Foo(1), Foo("a")))
```

the code correctly typechecks. Obviously you don't want to specify those types explicitly though.

According to my understanding the compiler can't infer good `B` and `tupler.Out` because they are not coupled tight enough to `In` and `A`. One way you can work this around is by introducing an intermediate trait like this:

```
trait Extractor[L <: HList, HF] {
  type FR <: HList
  type TR
  val folder: RightFolder.Aux[L, Foo[HNil], HF, Foo[FR]]
  val tupler: Tupler.Aux[FR, TR]
}

object Extractor {
  type Aux[L <: HList, HF, FR0 <: HList, TR0] = Extractor[L, HF] {type FR = FR0; type TR = TR0}

  implicit def wrap[L <: HList, In, HF, FR0 <: HList, TR0](implicit folder0: RightFolder.Aux[L, Foo[HNil], HF, Foo[FR0]],
                                                           tupler0: Tupler.Aux[FR0, TR0]) = new Extractor[L, HF] {
    type FR = FR0
    type TR = TR0
    override val folder = folder0
    override val tupler = tupler0
  }
}
```

and then using it like this:

```
def extract[In, A <: HList, B <: HList, C](keys: In)
                                          (implicit gen: Generic.Aux[In, A],
                                           extractor: Extractor.Aux[A, extractFold.type, B, C])
: Foo[C] = {
  val hli = gen.to(keys)
  val fr = extractor.folder(hli, Foo(HNil))
  Foo(extractor.tupler(fr.a))
}
```

This is a hacky solution but at least it seem to work (see also [online demo](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/bxXs88AERCqKJWdfqsE3ZQ)).

Comment: thank you for the reply. this approach obeys inference if i type it like `val result: Foo[(Int, String)] = extract(...)`, without the type hint it resolves to `Foo[Nothing]`

Comment: @AlexFoxGill, I probably miss something but this is not what I see. If I write `val r2 = extract((Foo(1), Foo("a")))` and then try to assign it to `val r3a:Foo[(Int, String)] = r2`, it works, but `val r3b:Foo[Nothing] = r2` fails. See the [modified demo](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/n3krvWWKTmWHDMjiW5RYDw). Could you tell me how you reproduce the issue?

Comment: perhaps i missed something, i'll try again and confirm

Comment: i could not replicate - i am using scalajs so perhaps that's why. however the other reply put me onto the right track which was to use `Comapped` as a witness to link `A` and `B`